# Retrieve DBpedia Flim data subject categories with SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Is there any way to extract the `dcterm:subject` of all the **film data** in DBpedia with SPARQL?

Like this:

```
Category:Films_set_in_1982
Category:Best_Drama_Picture_Golden_Globe_winners
Category:Best_Picture_Academy_Award_winners
………………
```

Comment: Your goal is not clear.  What do you consider "film data"?  What is the purpose of the query you're trying to execute?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a good start for you

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?cat WHERE {
  ?resource dcterms:subject* ?cat .
  ?cat ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Films>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PREFIX dataset: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dcterms:<http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
select ?o
where { ?s  a   dataset:Film ;
            ?p  ?o . 
        filter ( ?p = dcterms:subject )
      }
```

This worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean retrieve all the movies in DBpedia (titles in English), try this:

```
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
select ?l where {
?s a dataset:Film.
?s rdfs:label ?l.
FILTER langMatches( lang(?l), "en" ) 
}
```